# python if-statement with IndentationError

Tags: python, if-statement, sqlite

I have wrote a function to get commands in my database and now I am trying to write a function with more specify detail to enter to my database.But there is an error when I add a `elif statement`

Before:(Success)(ps :user is going to input function of the command first, if user input "switch" in the device buttom , he will get commands from my switch table, else he will get commands from router"):

```
def readciscodevice(function, device):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if device == "switch":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read
        elif device == "router":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;
a = input("function:")
b = input("device:")
for result in readciscodevice(a,b):
        print(result[0])
```

Then, I am trying to create a table called "showcommand" as show commands do not need to press "configure terminal" so I will make one more if statement but it seems not working...

After I add a if statement:

```
def readciscodevice(function, device):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        if device == "switch":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read
        elif device == "router":
                cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM router WHERE   function =? or function='configure terminal' or function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;
        elif device == "showcommand":
                 cur.execute(
                        "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM showcommand WHERE   function =? or  function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                        (function,))
                read = cur.fetchall()
                return read;


a = input("function:")
b = input("device:")
for result in readciscodevice(a,b):
        print(result[0])
```

The main error(which is int my last elif-statement[showcommand]) :

```
read = cur.fetchall()
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

and
return read;

```
Trailing semicolon in the statement less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects trailing semicolons in statements.
```

I dun know what is going on?
It looks no any problem in my mind but the problem is real.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Your indentation is off for `read = cur.fetchall()`, as your error clearly tells you.

Comment: In the first line of the `showcommand` block, you seem to have an extra space.

Comment: oh all of you are correct!

Comment: sorry for asking a careless mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have one space indent that should not be there

```
    elif device == "showcommand":
            cur.execute(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT command FROM showcommand WHERE   function =? or  function='enable'  ORDER BY key ASC",
                    (function,))
            read = cur.fetchall()
            return read;
```

Answer (score 2):

The line in that block starting cur.execute seems to be indented one more space than the other lines.